# Modeling entities in C# to write effiecient search queries using Nest.Net elasticsearch

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am using Nest.Net as Elastic Search client.

I have 2 entities. Lets say Book, Store.

```
  Book
  ------------
  Id
  ISBN
  Title

  Store
  ------------
  Id
  Name
```

A book with same ISBN can be available in multiple stores.

So I will have another mapping entity to maintain the book & store relationships as follows.,

```
Book_Store
-------------
Id
BookId
StoreId
```

In-order to get the list of books available in a particular store, I have below options

1. Use parent-child relationship of elasticsearch. But a book can be available in multiple stores and a store can have multiple books. So parent/child is not the correct approach logically.
2. Index all 3 entities and write queries to get the result.
3. Have an array "BookIds" in Store entity and index them.

In the above 3 options, which one is the correct one?

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track with Option 3.  Elasticsearch is a document store, not a relational database, so I tend to steer away from any relational/normalized type approaches.

You may want to consider taking it one step further, and use the [nested type](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html#mapping-nested-type).  With this approach you could store not only book ids, but entire book documents inside your store documents, allowing you to search for books in a store by more than just id (title, ISBN, etc...).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If I use nested type, what about performance? A store can have millions of books. So editing & re-indexing store object will create performance issues as it has to recreate / reindex  the books as well?

Comment: Well, you can use the [update api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html) for updating the nested docs as opposed to reindexing.  If you have tons of book ids and significantly less store ids, then it might make sense to nest the Store documents, or add an array of store ids inside in your Book documents instead.  Then you could just filter books by store.